# passing complex parameters from php to python

Tags: python

Here's the problem :

```
<?php
$x = '1 2 3';
echo shell_exec('python xyz.py .$x');
?>
```

and in Python :

```
x = sys.argv[1]
print (x)
```

it prints `1` which is obvious as it is breaking the parameters passed with space as delimiter.

So I can go ahead doing something like

```
string = ''
for word in sys.argv[1:]:
    string += word + '
```

but it'll stop me from sending any other parameters after `$x` because length of `$x` wouldn't be known and `sys.argv[1:]` would take everything after `argv[1]` as a single parameter

Another possible solution is using static delimiter like `#`, replacing spaces with `#` in PHP, then replacing `#` with spaces. This will work, but it is a trivial way to solve the problem.

so, is there any other solution to this?

Comment: its not clear what you want to achive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is shell stuff, not python (or php) specific... The bash script version:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "number of args : $#"
i=1
for arg
do
 echo "arg $((i++)) : $arg"
done


bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground/shpy$ ./test.sh 1 2 3
number of args : 3
arg 1 : 1
arg 2 : 2
arg 3 : 3
bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground/shpy$ ./test.sh '1 2 3'
number of args : 1
arg 1 : 1 2 3
```

The Python version:

```
import sys

args = sys.argv[1:]
print "number ogf args: %s" % len(args)
for i, arg in enumerate(args, 1):
    print "arg %s : %s" % (i, arg)



bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground/shpy$ python test.py 1 2 3
number ogf args: 3
arg 1 : 1
arg 2 : 2
arg 3 : 3
bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground/shpy$ python test.py '1 2 3'
number ogf args: 1
arg 1 : 1 2 3
```

=> If you want "1 2 3" to be understood a a single argument, you do have to quote it, ie:

```
<?php
$x = '1 2 3';
echo shell_exec("python xyz.py '$x'");
?>
```

Comment: Worked like charms. Thanks Bruno.

Comment: @DevenAhluwalia: then feel free to accept my answer.

Comment: SO mob app doesn't have provision to accept answers :D